# How to obtain value from dynamic table in Reactive Form?

Tags: angular

This is the snippet of my code, I can add new table row if needed, but how to take the value from table in ngFor? *Table is inside reactive form

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of tableRow; let i = index">
 <th scope="row" class="text-center">{{ i+1 }}</th>

 <td>
  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="supplierRequirementDesc" placeholder="e.g Wiring & Piping" formControlName="suppReqInput">
  </div>
 </td>

 <td>
  <div class="form-group">
   <select class="form-control" id="supplierUnitPcs" formControlName="suppUnitPcsInput">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Pcs</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </td>

 <td>
  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="supplierQuantityInput" placeholder="Quantity" formControlName="suppQuantityInput">
  </div>
 </td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-form" (click)="addTableRow()">+ Add new item</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-form" (click)="deleteRow()">- Remove item</button>
```

This is current data from console.log
Title: abc
Description: def
Company based in: ghi
Company Type: 2
Supplier Category: 4
Bond Value: 100
Verified: Yes
***Supplier Requirement: zbc***
***Supplier Unit: 2***
***Supplier Quantity: 1257***
Supplier Notes: xzx

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50595070/angular-how-to-get-input-value-at-ngfor-loop-with-one-way-binding) . This may help you.

Comment: you have build your array using reactive form arrays https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#dynamic-controls-using-form-arrays

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `row`

```
(click)="getTableRow(row)"
```

get value

```
getTableRow(row)
{
   console.log(row)
}
```

Comment: He asks for getting form value. will row obj send form value too!

Comment: @Sivaramakrishnan sorry i didnt get it what

Comment: the reactive form control value is needed, not a row object values.

Answer (score 0):

I think for each iteration there is a separate form group and each form group has a separate form control object, that can reuse the class methods. so I suggest a small change to the previous answer,
add below Html to all input tags.

```
//In HTML

(ngModelChange) = takeValues(this.suppUnitPcsInput.value);

//In component
takeValues(values){
    console.log(values)
}
```

And once the 'addRow' button is clicked, then row adding process can be done.

Comment: Not quite understand with this. Currently, I'm only able to obtain value from only one row from the table even though I have added two rows, and this table is in form, I can obtain other value, no problem, my problem is how to obtain and store the value from the iterable table. Do I need to declare new formgroup?